# What is the compactness uniqueness argument

Tags: compactness, inverse-problems

I have come across the term "compactness uniqueness argument" in many inverse problems papers and books but the proof are usually omitted. Could anyone give such an example and relevant references?

Comment: What kind of statement (what kind of uniqueness?) is this sort of argument supposed to prove?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered unless you show or link or cite at least one (complete) example. The only things  that come to my mind are (1). If $X, Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous  bijection  then $f$ is a homeomorphism... (2). If $T,U$ are   compact Hausdorff topologies on $X$ and $U\subset T$ , then $U=T$. Because  $id_X$ is a continuous bijection from $(X, T)$ to $(X,U)$ so by (1), $  id_X $  is a homeomorphism from $(X,T)$ to $ (X,U)$.

Comment: Could you give an example of a reference to where the argument is used?